# How to make Maven Javadoc Plugin work with any Java version

Tags: java, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm using Maven Javadoc Plugin like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have multiple JDK versions installed and want to be able to build a project with any of them. The above configuration works fine with Java 8, but it fails with Java 11 with the following error

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.1:jar
>   (attach-javadocs) on project ...: MavenReportException: Error while
>   generating Javadoc: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment
>   variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set.

The obvious solution is to set JAVA_HOME. But as I mentioned, I have multiple versions of JDK, so reconfiguring JAVA_HOME every time I want to use another version wouldn't be convenient at all.

Another solution (from [Unable to find javadoc command - maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961615/unable-to-find-javadoc-command-maven)) is to add the following configuration to the plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
</configuration>
```

This makes it work with Java 11, but breaks Java 8 because the `javadoc` location is `${java.home}/../bin/javadoc` in that case.

Ideally I always want to use `javadoc` from the directory where the java executable that Maven uses is, but I haven't found a way to do it with Maven Javadoc Plugin.

Comment: "This makes it work with Java 11, but breaks Java 8 because the javadoc location is ${java.home}/../bin/javadoc in that case."  How it comes Java 8 `javadoc` is `${java.home}/../bin/javadoc`? I checked myself Java 8. It is `${java.home}/bin/javadoc`

Comment: @QingfeiYuan Try running `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));` with JDK 8. The output will be `<your jdk directory>/jre`, while `javadoc` is in `<your jdk directory>/bin`.

Comment: oh.. If so, that's easy, don't use `${java.home}`. use `{$JAVA_HOME}` this environment variable is defined by you.

Comment: @QingfeiYuan Please reread my question. I explained why I don't want to use JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) may be able to help.

Add something like this to your POM.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk-8-config</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>1.8</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/../bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>jdk-11-config</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>11</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <javadocExecutable>${java.home}/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

JDK ranges are also possible, read more on those in the linked doc.

Maven will pick up the version of Java being used to run itself, activate the correct profile, and define the property correct.

A caveat - typically we build with `JAVA_HOME` set, or via Jenkins which can be configured to define `JAVA_HOME` per job. This approach works well in those cases.

You could also investigate Maven toolchains. I have no experience with those, other than reading they help make it easier to define tool locations on various machines.

Comment: It worked fine with JDK 7-12, thanks! I edited your answer to add the correct javadoc path for other people who might have the same questions. I used it like this in the maven-javadoc-plugin plugin configuration `<configuration><javadocExecutable>${javadocExecutable}</javadocExecutable></configuration>`.

Comment: Using that property name, you may not need explicit plugin config. The name of the property is the right name for configuring the value in the plugin - the 'User property' specified for this element in [the plugin mojo doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html)

Comment: You're correct. I didn't realize it. The configuration from my previous comment is not required.