# Error "the JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly" on running "mvn clean javadoc:jar package"

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

When I try to execute the command

`mvn clean javadoc:jar package`

it shows

> the JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. This environment variable is needed to run this program.

> NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK, not a JRE.

I checked out the already asked question *[Unable to find javadoc command - maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961615/unable-to-find-javadoc-command-maven)* and the solution I tried above were taken from this solution only. I am new to Ubuntu. How can I fix this?

Whereas when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` it prints:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

I also tried setting the `JAVA_HOME` to:

1. `/etc/launchd.conf/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
2. `/usr/libexec/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
3. `/usr/libexec/java-11-openjdk-amd64/`

When I run `mvn -v`, it prints:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.0-45-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

And when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` it prints:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: this is my maven : mvn -v java path `Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre` so try to update java path with `/jre` at the end and tell me if it worked.

Comment: @MohamedBdr By doing that I get the error I mentioned initially.

Comment: @ThunderKnight Have you installed Java via a packet manager?

Comment: @JanezKuhar I have installed it with the help of terminal

Comment: It may be that you've installed [`openjdk-11-jre`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/java/openjdk-11-jre) instead of [`openjdk-11-jdk`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/java/openjdk-11-jdk).

Comment: How do I check whether I have `openjdk-11-jre` or `openjdk-11-jdk`

Comment: @JanezKuhar What do you get after running `java -version`

Comment: try this command too `sudo apt list --installed | grep -i openjdk`

Comment: I get ```WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

openjdk-11-jdk-headless/focal-updates,focal-security,now 11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jdk/focal-updates,focal-security,now 11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jre-headless/focal-updates,focal-security,now 11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jre/focal-updates,focal-security,now 11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: can you try this `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin` and don't forget to use `source ~/.bash_profile` and please tell me did you use bashrc or bash_profile ?

Comment: @Mohamed `source ~/.bash_profile` to use this command where? Also, I don't know about about `bashrc`, I used this link to download https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: alright so you set here all the environment variables to `/etc/environment` so you need to run `source /etc/environment` every time you make a change so please try to update your java path to /jre/bin and then you must run `source /etc/environment` and then try mvn again

Comment: @MohamedBdr Sorry, but can you please give the commands as an answer, will really appreciate it, I am not very well used to ubuntu

Comment: no problem 1- `sudo nano /etc/environment` 2- `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin"` 3- `source /etc/environment` 4- `mvn clean javadoc:jar package`

Comment: @MohamedBdr I did this what should I set PATH variable now?

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin` you need to insert that inside your bash profile `vi ~/.bash_profile` and please tell me what `echo $PATH` shows

Comment: and did you have `/usr/java` path or not `cd /usr/java`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230117/discussion-between-thunderknight-and-mohamed-bdr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the [above listed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704357/the-java-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined-correctly-error-on-running-mvn/66706921#comment117915132_66704357) with pattern `openjdk-11-.*` (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086462/how-can-i-remove-uninstall-list-of-packages-immediately-after-searching-them-wi)) and install Java [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504825/how-to-install-jdk-11-under-ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm..., probably the file doesn’t exist for running javadoc. Does the file */usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc* exist?

Please try:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac (big Sur) I was getting the same problem. After reading this [article](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/) ; this command worked for my enviroment:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```